# Vertx: pass initial data to verticle on it deployment

Tags: java, vert.x

*How can I pass copy of `int[][]` array to verticle on it deployment?*

I have a `ServerVerticle` from which deploy 5-10 `ServiceVerticle`s.

Each of `ServiceVerticle` must use the same shared data structure - `Map<Integer, Short[]>` which can be 100-2000 Mb.

Problem - I can't create `Local` map with array as a value.

The only in-memory solution I see - pass copy of `int[][]` to each `ServiceVerticle` on it deployment and keep 5-10 copies of data.

P.S. This data structure must have as fast as possible lookup, so I dislike cluster-wide solutions like Hazelcast `IMap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there isn't much freedom in the types you can use in a `LocalMap` you can use `Buffer`s. A buffer is an optimized byte array and you can quickly adapt it to your use case. Using a `Buffer` also means you will have a compact in memory representation so you can save memory and any operations will be fast.

You only need to write a transformation from a 2D plane to a 1D line. For example say that you have the following array (2 x 3):

```
int[][] data = new int[] {
  new int[] {1, 2, 3},
  new int[] {4, 5, 6},
};
```

If you transform it to a buffer:

```
Buffer.buffer()
  .appendInt(1).appendInt(2).appendInt(3)
  .appendInt(4).appendInt(5).appendInt(6);
```

(You can later just use the byte representation, this is just to illustrate how it works).

Now you can refer to any `x`, `y` by doing:

```
int getInt(int x, int y) {
  // transform from 2D to 1D
  int pos = y * LENGTH + x;
  // Where LENGTH is the the example: 3

  // For safety assert on length
  if (pos > buffer.length()) throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
  // TODO: assert on min, max (x, y)

  return buffer.getInt(pos);
}
```